# Conversion of JavaScript to userscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, greasemonkey, userscripts

I have a JavaScript running making ajax calls to a server.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var div = '<div id="OverlayDialog">';
    $.Coral = function (options) {
        $.extend(options, {
            data: JSON.stringify(options.data),
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                'Content-Encoding': 'abc',
                'Target': options.operation
            },

            dataFilter: function(data, type) {
                return data || "{}";
            }
        });
        return $.ajax(options);
    };

    $.MyService = function (options) {
        $.extend(options, {
            url: "link to myservice",
            operation: 'dummyOperation'
        });
        return $.Coral(options);
    };

    function test() {

        try {
            var myOptionsData = {
                storeUrlList: [document.getElementById('normalizedStoreUrl1').value,document.getElementById('normalizedStoreUrl2').value]
            };
            var myOptions = {data: myOptionsData,crossDomain: true};
            response = $.MyService(myOptions).responseText;
            var subString = "";
            var startIndex = response.indexOf('{',1);
            var endIndex = response.lastIndexOf('}');
            responseText = response.substring(startIndex,endIndex);
            var subString = JSON.parse(responseText);
            var map2 = new Map();
            $.each( subString, function( key, value ) {
                var map1 = new Map();
                div+='<p>'+JSON.stringify(key)+'</p>';
                $.each( value, function( ky, val ) {
                    console.log('ky => '+ky);
                    console.log('val => '+val);
                    map1.set(ky, val);
                    div += '<p>'+JSON.stringify(ky)+':'+JSON.stringify(val)+'</p>';
                  });   

              });
        } catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
        div += '</div>';
        $('body').append(div);
        return false;
    }

</script>
```

The script runs just fine for me.
I want to convert this into a greasemonkey script while displaying the results in a separate dialog using jqueryUI dialog. The part of creating an overlay dialog and writing data into it works fine, but I am not able to execute the .$MyOptions and .$Coral functionsin the userScript.

Below is the userScript I am using:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Get Data for each unique URL
// @namespace   SellerSupportScript
// @include     *
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js
// @resource    jqUI_CSS  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @grant       GM_getResourceText
// @grant       GM_getResourceURL
// @run-at      document-end
// allow pasting
// ==/UserScript==

var snapshotResults = document.evaluate('//a[contains(@href,"http")]/@href', document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
var windowWidth = $(window).width()-800;
var windowHeight = 'auto';
var div = '<div id="SSOverlayDialog">';

var zNode = document.createElement ('input');
zNode.setAttribute ('id', 'SSButton');
zNode.setAttribute( 'type', 'image' );
zNode.setAttribute( 'src', 'http://www.veryicon.com/icon/64/System/Longhorn%20R2/Back%20Button.png');

document.body.appendChild (zNode);

var uniqueHostnameSet = new Set();
var uniqueURLArray = [];
uniqueHostnameSet.add(window.location.hostname);
var finalUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname;
uniqueURLArray.push(finalUrl);
var linkToDisplay = '<a href="' + finalUrl + '">' + finalUrl + '</a>';
linkToDisplay += '<br/><br/>';
div += linkToDisplay;
for (var iterate = 0; iterate < snapshotResults.snapshotLength; iterate++)
{
  var hrefContent = snapshotResults.snapshotItem(iterate).textContent;
  var regex = /http.*/;
  var href = regex.exec(hrefContent);
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = href;
  if (!uniqueHostnameSet.has(a.hostname))
  {
    uniqueHostnameSet.add(a.hostname);
    finalUrl = a.protocol + '//' + a.hostname;
    uniqueURLArray.push(finalUrl);
    linkToDisplay = '<a href="' + finalUrl + '">' + finalUrl + '</a>';
    linkToDisplay += '<br/><br/>';
    div += linkToDisplay;
  }
}

var size = 10;
for (var i=0; i<uniqueURLArray.length; i+=size) {
    var urlList = uniqueURLArray.slice(i,i+size);
    try {
        var myOptionsData = {
          storeUrlList: urlList
        };
        var myOptions = {data: myOptionsData,crossDomain: true};
        response = $.MyService(myOptions).responseText;
        var subString = "";
        var startIndex = response.indexOf('{',1);
        var endIndex = response.lastIndexOf('}');
        responseText = response.substring(startIndex,endIndex);
        var subString = JSON.parse(responseText);
        var AttributeMap = {};
        var map2 = new Map();
        $.each( subString, function( key, value ) {
            var map1 = new Map();
            div+='<p>'+JSON.stringify(key)+'</p>';
            $.each( value, function( ky, val ) {
                console.log('ky => '+ky);
                console.log('val => '+val);
                map1.set(ky, val);
                div += '<p>'+JSON.stringify(ky)+'->'+JSON.stringify(val)+'</p>';
                div += '<br/><br/>'
              });   
            map2.set(key, map1);
          });
      } catch(e) {
        alert(e);
      }

}
div += '</div>';
$('body').append(div);

$('#mobiusSSOverlayDialog').dialog({

  autoOpen: false,
  modal: false,
  title: 'Unique URLs on Page (press "Esc" button to close)',
  position: {
    at: 'right top'
  },
  width: windowWidth,
  height: windowHeight,
  zIndex: 11111111,
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Close',
      click: function () {
        $(this).dialog('close');
      }
    }
  ]
});

//}
$("#SSButton").click(function() {

     ($("#SSOverlayDialog").dialog("isOpen") == false) ? $("#SSOverlayDialog").dialog("open") : $("#SSOverlayDialog").dialog("close") ;
 });

var jqUI_CssSrc = GM_getResourceText('jqUI_CSS');
jqUI_CssSrc = jqUI_CssSrc.replace(/\.ui-front \{[\s]*z-index:\s100\;[\s]*\}/g,".ui-front \{\n z-index: 10000000 \; \n\}");
GM_addStyle(jqUI_CssSrc);
//--- Style our newly added elements using CSS.
GM_addStyle ( multilineStr ( function () {/*!
    #SSButton {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 22222222;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
*/} ) );

function multilineStr (dummyFunc) {
    var str = dummyFunc.toString ();
    str     = str.replace (/^[^\/]+\/\*!?/, '') // Strip function () { /*!
            .replace (/\s*\*\/\s*\}\s*$/, '')   // Strip */ }
            .replace (/\/\/.+$/gm, '') // Double-slash comments wreck CSS. Strip them.
            ;
    return str;
}

$.Coral = function (options) {
        $.extend(options, {
            data: JSON.stringify(options.data),
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                'Content-Encoding': 'abc',
                'Target': options.operation
            },

            dataFilter: function(data, type) {
                return data || "{}";
            }
        });
        return $.ajax(options);
    };

    $.MyService = function (options) {
        $.extend(options, {
            url: "link to myservice",
            operation: 'dummyOperation'
        });
        return $.Coral(options);
    };
```

I get the following error in the alert box:

> TypeError: $.MyService is not a function

Can someone help how to overcome this ?

I looked up the problem on stackoverflow itself but could not find a previous question pertaining to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `$.MyService()` before you define it at the end. A function declared like

`var functionName = function () {...`

is only defined for code after it in the scope, whereas a function declared like

`function functionName() {...`

is defined for all code in the same scope.